# useEffect and event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to update a database after an event is emitted from `contract`. I'm concerned about instances where the `contract` emits **another** `SomeEvent` before the DB operations finish, causing the `useEffect` to retrigger before the first update is complete. Is this a genuine concern and how is it usually handled?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        contract.on("SomeEvent", (_a, _b) => {
            ...perform DB operations here!
        })

        /* Handle unmounts */
        return () => {
            contract.removeAllListeners("SomeEvent");
        }
    }, [])
```

Comment: Why would the `useEffect` trigger more than once (or twice with `<StrictMode>`)? Or are you asking about what happens when event handling overlaps? If so, this has nothing to do with React or its hooks

Comment: Hi Phil - I guess understanding what happens when event handling overlaps is more accurate? How is it irrelevant? If the event emits when a contract does something (say adding a user), and I'm in the process of updating my DB to reflect the change, but before all DB operations complete, another user is added causing the hook to rerender, then obviously this has ramifications. There is no queue mechanism with hooks from my understanding. This will be especially relevant while dealing with high frequency data

Comment: Using an empty dependency array in your effect hook means it should only run once on mount (ignoring `<StrictMode>` for simplicity). Re-renders shouldn't make it run again. In any case, your hook only registers listeners on mount and removes listeners on cleanup. Any concurrency concerns are in the domain of whatever `contract` is. Like I said, nothing to do with React or hooks

Comment: Without information on whatever `contract` is or what _"perform DB operations"_ even means, this is impossible to answer. I suggest you consult the relevant documentation and look through any available _Issues_ lists

Comment: You could create a queue using the `useState` hook and another state `isUpdating` to check if the database is currently being updated or not.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make the event listener a promise chain, so the next event only runs after the previous event finishes (by awaiting the asychronous function).

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let queue = Promise.resolve();

    contract.on("SomeEvent", (_a, _b) => {
        queue = queue.then(async () => {
            // perform async DB operations here!
            await dbOperation(_a, _b);
        });
    });

    /* Handle unmounts */
    return () => {
        contract.removeAllListeners("SomeEvent");
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: Nice client-side solution but this should ultimately be implemented on the server-side using locking / atomic transactions. The problem with this solution is that it works for a single client when in reality there would be multiple clients operating in parallel